# How can I put these codes into function.php in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to upload file with Chinese character to a WordPress website. However, the name of the file is gibberish.  I have searched the question and found some solutions. One is to modify the //wp-admin/includes/file.php

```
    function wp_handle_upload( &$file, $overrides = false, $time = null ) {
//….
// Move the file to the uploads dir
//$new_file = $uploads['path'] . “/$filename”;
$new_file = $uploads['path'] . “/” . iconv(“UTF-8″,”GB2312″,$filename);
//…
//return apply_filters( ‘wp_handle_upload’, array( ‘file’ => $new_file, ‘url’ => $url, ‘type’ => $type ), ‘upload’ );
return apply_filters( ‘wp_handle_upload’, array( ‘file’ => $uploads['path'] . “/$filename”, ‘url’ => $url, ‘type’ => $type ) , ‘upload’);
}
```

As I know, it changes the encoding of the filename. But I want to put it in the function.php in the theme folder. What can I do ?

Comment: Why do you have fancy quotes in your code? Don't use those, use regular `"` and `'` for coding.

Comment: It's right in my website, just some copy mistake

Comment: Have you tried putting this in functions.php?